# How to have different body designs in html erb file connected through render in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

So I have two versions of my index "home page": One for signed-in users, one for non-signed in.  The signed in users page is simple with a blank white background.  However, I want the _landingpage partial (which is populated through `render` for non-signed-in users) to have an image as it's background.

The code below just gives me a simple white background (no sign of the image) for both index and _landingpage.

What is the way to resolve this?

index.html.erb

```
<body style="text-align: center !important; width: 60%; margin: 0 auto; margin: auto !important;">

<% if user_signed_in? %>

<h3>you have succesfully signed in</h3>


<% else %>

<%= render "landingpage" %>

<% end %>


</body>
```

_landingpage.html.erb

```
<body style="text-align: center !important; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; margin: auto !important;     background-image:url('http://example.jpg'); color: white;">
<h1> welcome!</h1>
<%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path, :method => :get %>
<%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :method => :get %>

</body>
```

Comment: You are having two bodies... You should only have one. Add your body /body tags under your "if"

Comment: Can you show the application.html.erb file please? And also is there an image at your pointed url? I doubt that.

Comment: That's precisely my question: I want to have two separate bodies for each separate page.  Or at least have two distinct backgrounds.  Is this possible?  @uDay example.jpg is nothing, my real image works but it was a long string so I did not post it.

Comment: render different `layouts` instead. Put the logic which `layout` to use in to the controller.

Comment: I agree with @marczking - render two different layouts from controller depending on if the user is signed in or not.